# openni_audio for Xtion Pro Live

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use two microphones of Xtion Pro Live sensor for my research. I found a package *openni_audio* here, https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_audio

After remove line #9 () in manifest.xml file (I cannot find any package named as "openni"), I can make the package. However, I don't know how to run/launch the node because there is no launch file.

Can anybody can share your experience with this node?

To Mr. Micheal Ferguson, thank for your code. But could you share more?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45461/openni_audio-for-xtion-pro-live/) by [Quang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3354/quang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is highly experimental code that *just barely works* -- really more a proof of concept than anything else. ROS doesn't have much in the way of audio support and so you won't find much that works with the output of this node (there is an example script in Python which might happen to play audio using the 'ao' library).

That said, this is designed to be a nodelet that you would add to your normal openni launch file. It would look something like:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="driver" 
       args="load openni_audio/AudioNodelet $(arg manager) $(arg bond)"
       respawn="$(arg respawn)">
    <param name="channel" value="0" />
 </node>
```

if you were to add it directly to the openni launch files. The important parameter is 'channel' which specifies which microphone to connect to. If you want to connect to both sides, you would spawn two nodelets, each serving a different channel.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1